# Vue: Child string prop wont render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I'm new to vue and am trying to understand its one-way data bind model component registration and passing props.

In my `index.js` I have my parent component in which I want to render a single child right now

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import StyledTitle from './components/StyledTitle'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    StyledTitle,
  },
})
```

Child Component is `StyledTitle.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import styled from 'vue-styled-components'

const StyledTitle = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff4947;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: #f07079;
  }
`

Vue.component('styled-title', {
  props: ['text'],
  components: {
    'styled-title': StyledTitle,
  },
  template: `<StyledTitle>{{ text }}</StyledTitle>`,
})

export default StyledTitle
```

Finally my HTML is which I expect to render a red Hi

```
<div id="app">
   <styled-title text="Hi"></styled-title>
</div>
```

The HI is not showing up though and the props value is undefined. Coming to this from react so wondering why this isnt working, thanks!

Ps screenshot of my vue devtools
[image]

Comment: @MarkMeyer no errors in console that are relevant to the app. I'll add a screenshot of my vue devtools though. const StyledTitle = styled.h1`` is how you declare a styled component.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pass the `text` as a prop instead of just setting it in the default slot?

Comment: @Phil Component def works if I just pass Hi between the opening and closing tags but I wanted to get props to work for future cases where I may have more dynamic content than just "Hi" coming from an API or some other data object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `StyledTitle.js` file exports a normal styled `<h1>` component which uses a default slot for its content instead of your custom component that accepts a `text` prop.

If you're still keen on using a prop-based component, you need to export that instead of the one from `vue-styled-components`. You should avoid global component registration in this case too.

For example

```js
// StyledTitle.js
import styled from 'vue-styled-components'

// create a styled title locally
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff4947;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: #f07079;
  }
`

// now export your custom wrapper component
export default {
  name: 'StyledTitle',
  props: ['text'],
  components: {
    Title, // locally register your styled Title as "Title"
  },
  template: `<Title>{{ text }}</Title>`,
})
```

---

Given your component doesn't maintain any state, you could make it [purely functional](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components). Using a render function will also help, especially if your Vue runtime doesn't include the template compiler (which is the default for most Vue CLI apps)

```js
export default {
  name: 'StyledTitle',
  functional: true,
  props: { text: String },
  render: (h, { props }) => h(Title, props.text)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works, does Vue have anything in the docs that you know of outlining this pattern? I didnt quite understand what they had in the docs under props.

Comment: @gwar9 I'm not really sure what you mean when you say _"this pattern"_.

Comment: I suppose this is a vue styled components thing more than it is a vue components thing. By pattern I was wondering about the export default object where you set the component name, props, component to use, and its template instead of say using Vue.Component as I was trying to do.

Comment: Using `Vue.component()` [registers your component globally](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration). What you have and what I've got in my answer is a component created and exported in `StyledTitle.js` that can be imported and used via [local registration](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) in other components. Components are just objects with properties like `props`, `template`, `components`, etc. The `name` property isn't particularly important and is only really used for debugging.